# php include not working on mamp

Tags: php, mamp

The require_once statement in my code is not working on MAMP. The same code was working perfectly on WAMP earlier before I ported the project over.

```
require_once('class\validate_group.php');
```

The error I get with this is:

```
Warning: require_once(class\validate_group.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/validate_login.php on line 37
```

The phpinfo.php is showing the include path as:

```
.:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs
```

"class" is a folder inside htdocs

Strangely when I reverse the slash it starts reading the validate_group.php file. Will the reversed slashes still work in AWS where I am finally going to host this?

Comment: Simple use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR like this `require_once('class'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'validate_group.php');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, backslash in PHP is normally used to escape characters.

So you've escaped the `\validate_group.php` file in your `require_once` call.

You can use a pre-defined constant such as:

`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to avoid this in future.

Answer (score 1):

Simple use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` like below

```
require_once('class'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'validate_group.php');
```